# Azure Synapse Analytics version control

Tags: azure, architecture, liquibase, flyway, azure-synapse

I've used [Liquibase](https://www.liquibase.org/) and [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org/) for RDBMs version control earlier. I see Flyway [has support of Snowflake](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/), so it's okay to use version control with MPP Data Warehouse.

*Is there any version control solution for Azure Synapse Analytics? What is considered the best approach?*

I can't find any version control solution with direct support for Azure Synapse Analytics. Liquibase has SQL Server support and notion about "Other databases", but I'm still not sure  - *how wise it is to use Liquibase for Synapse Analytics? Will it work? How many issues?*

Currently I saw the [Visual Studio 2019 integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-install-visual-studio) doc. But I can't understand from the provided doc if VS 2019 will manage schema updates and rollbacks for me. Also part of team use Macbooks - means no support for Visual Studio. Currently we're doing deployment of sql script through Terraform and going to implement custom version control solution.

Comment: I couldn't get Liquibase to work with Synapse owing to the fact Synapse doesn't allow Primary Keys and the Liquibase tables that are created require them.

Answer (score 1):

You can try it with [liquibase](https://www.liquibase.org/) and the `mssql` since Azure Synapse Analytics should be compatible from the TSQL part and the connection details.

If you still face any different behavior you can extend  at the `MSSQLDatabase` in the [github repository](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/master/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/database/core/MSSQLDatabase.java) and change the Azure Synapse Analytics specific part.

Comment: thanks for your answer! Currently we're going to try Visual Studio, since it's already integrated in Azure Devops. Will provide with update...

Comment: Great - please let me know the outcome if it is working

Comment: sure, I think I'll have the results in a 2-4 weeks

Comment: Hey @VB_ - any update on how this went in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

I have recently used VS(SSDT) for SQL dedicated pool (SQL DW) database projects on GitHub and Git(Azure DevOps) repos. Also there is support for CI/CD pipelines in Azure DevOps. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-query-visual-studio)